# How to enter keys during animation

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to 
1. enter keys in an entry-widget while an image is animated on a canvas and
2. start a procedure when the enter-key is pressed.
 Below you can see what I did till now. In additon I tried out several things with

```
bind . "<Key>" "onKeyPressed %K"
```

but the keys don't appear until the animation is finished and the application doesn't respond to the enter-key during the animation.
Do I have to use Tcl_CreateTimerHandler to solve the problem?

Please could you give me a help? Thanks in advance.
Oliver

```
#!/usr/bin/wish
proc ImageMove {Image} {
  .can move $Image 1 0
}

wm title . "Demo" 
wm geometry . +300+300
entry .en -textvariable Text
image create photo MyImage -file "pic.ppm"
canvas .can -height 200 -width 300
set MyImage2 [.can create image 0 0 -anchor nw -image MyImage]
pack .en
pack .can

for {set i 0} {$i<=100} {incr i} {
  ImageMove $MyImage2
  update idletask
  after 100
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure about it, but `update idletask` only processes events scheduled to run on next idle time. Maybe your problem disappears if you just use `update`.

But this is not good coding style. You should only have short running functions in your Tk application. And calling update has it's own problems, because you can't know what other functions might be called in the middle of your proc.

I suggest something like this:

```
proc animator {cnt lim} {
   global MyImage2
   ImageMove $MyImage2
   if {$cnt < $lim} then {
     after 100 animator [incr cnt] lim
   }
}

animator 0 100
```

Notice also the use of the parameter cnt a replacement for a global variable.